# Autoscroll a Bootstrap Row/Columns in Joomla Module

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, bootstrap

I am using a K2 Content module to display 'Sponsors' of an event. You can see an example [here](http://tbli.sitewidehosting.co.uk/conference?dev=1)

I have managed to set this up so that the columns can be scrolled manually using a mouse drag but ideally I would like this to be automatic i.e. Step through so that every x seconds the columns move one to the left.

Would this be simple to do? I've hunted around looking at bootstrap horizontal scrolling but haven't found anything relevant. Ideally I'd like this to have a carousel effect (so when it gets to the last sponsor it automatically loads the first).

The page source code is

```
    <?php
/**
 * @version     $Id: default.php 1766 2012-11-22 14:10:24Z lefteris.kavadas $
 * @package     K2
 * @author      JoomlaWorks http://www.joomlaworks.net
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006 - 2012 JoomlaWorks Ltd. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU/GPL license: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
 */
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<?php if ($params->get('feed')): ?>
    <div class="k2FeedIcon">
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&format=feed&moduleID=' . $module->id); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_THIS_RSS_FEED'); ?>" target="_blank">
            <span><?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_THIS_RSS_FEED'); ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="k2ModuleBox<?php echo $module->id; ?>" >

<?php if ($params->get('itemPreText')): ?>
    <p class="modulePretext"><?php echo $params->get('itemPreText'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (count($items)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($items as $key => $item): ?>
    <article class="clearfix">
        <header>
           <?php if ($params->get('itemTitle')): ?>
                <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a></h2>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </header>
        <section class="content">
            <?php if ($params->get('itemImage') || $params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('itemImage') && isset($item->image)): ?>
                    <div class="img">
                        <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_CONTINUE_READING'); ?> &quot;<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>&quot;">
                            <img src="<?php echo $item->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $item->introtext; ?>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </section>
        <section class="ft-wrp clearfix">
            <div class="container sponsors-scroll">
            <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap">
                <h4 class="rotate col-md-2">Sponsors</h4>
            <?php if ($params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($item->extra_fields)): ?>

                <?php $sponsors = array(); ?>
                <?php foreach ($item->extra_fields as $key => $fieldname): // regroup fields per level?> 
                    <?php if($fieldname->name === 'Url'):
                      $sponsors[$fieldname->alias][$fieldname->name] = $fieldname->url;
                    else:
                      $sponsors[$fieldname->alias][$fieldname->name] = $fieldname->value;
                    endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php
                    // define sort order for $sponsors array
                    $sort_order = array('Location','Collaborating Partner','Platinum', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze','Carbon Neutrality', 'Booth', 'Cocktail', 'Badge', 'Event Partner', 'Media', 'Global', 'USA', 'Europe', 'Asia');

                    // sort $sponsors based on sort order in $sort_order
                    usort($sponsors, function ($a, $b) use ($sort_order) {
                        return array_search($a['Level'], $sort_order) - array_search($b['Level'], $sort_order);
                    });

                ?>
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <?php foreach ($sponsors as $key=>$value) : ?>
                 <?php 
                     if($i%2 == 0) {
                        //echo $i > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
                        //echo "<div class='row-fluid'>";
                      }

                    ;?>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="spons-well">
                            <h4><small> <?php echo $value['Level'] ?> </small></h4>
                            <a href="<?php echo $value['Url'];?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $value['Logo'] ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <?php $i++ ;?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>   
              <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
      </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I'm really a novice when it comes to JS so if anyone has applied something like this before then your help would be most appreciated.

Best Regards
Donna

Comment: Hi Donna, please review your many prior questions and mark resolved pages with an accepted answer (and upvote answers that are helpful).  This properly dignifies / rewards the volunteers that deliver useful support.  Furthermore, it stops the system from "bumping" resolved pages to the top of the question pile.  Thank you for looking after the community that looks after you.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Donna apparently does not have time for these irrelevant things... :)

Comment: I'm going to keep praying that that isn't true.

Comment: Hi guys, I have been going though my previous questions and marking answers valid - however many answers are not valid and/or not relevant.

Comment: Thanks Donna.  For the question that do not have adequate answers, please comment to invested volunteers with what isn't quite right.   If anyone asked for clarification, please provided it.  All questions should progress to a system-recognized resolution.   1. Answer acceptance.  2. Question Closure  or 3. Question Retraction.

Comment: Downvoting incorrect content is just as important as upvoting correct content.  It is not intended to be a malicious act.  By not commenting/downvoting bad content, future researchers will waste time trying things that will not work.  For instance, before I found https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22632/12352 there were at least 3 researchers that upvoted (and possibly used) this answer that is very much wrong.  We must all do our part to refine the content in this community.  Thanks for the steps that you have taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply (if needed, customize for yourself) the **html `<div>`** structure, and use the **js,** and **css** from the examples (links) below:

https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/huten0wq/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=huten0wq

actually this is a better, I think last updated, source of this carousel:
https://github.com/solodev/infinite-carousel (it is better to copy the source codes from this github link).

**1.** For using the css, and js from the above link, you should just rename the `<section class="ft-wrp clearfix">` to `<section class="customer-logos">`  and `<div class="spons-well">` to `<div class="slide">` in your K2 layout in order to make it ready to work with the given css and javascript(jQuery), for example. Also you should wrap this carousel into

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
```

So it is not a huge job to use these on your layout. Maybe a little fine tuning needed, checking, modifying or deleting redundant divs in your current html structure, you have to work on that a bit...

**2.** The css from the link should be copied in your theme css, or custom.css file of your template and the jQuery(js) code should be copied within `<script></script>` tags at the bottom of your layout php file which you copied here, after the last closing html `</div>` tag (you could load these from external **js** file but now it is enough if you just include that in your layout)(the **css** could also be loaded from separate .css file but you can do that later. However, as later got clear, it is very important, that the **carousel.css** style has to loaded before the **jQuery script** starts to run on your site! Otherwise the carousel will look messed up a lot).

**3.** You have to make sure you load the 2 javascript/jQuery library in your HTML head or before your closing html body tag (if it's not there on your site yet):

**jQuery min** and **slick js**

you can just simply copy and paste it in the `<head></head>` of your page from here:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Or in a more Joomla standard way, you paste this code below to the top of your K2 layout file to load the required js libraries like the following (after the line: `defined('_JEXEC') or die;`) :

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'); // comment out this line if it's already loaded on your site.
$document->addScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js');
```

(As I see, Bootstrap is already loaded on your site so it's better if you do not load that again. If the jQuery library also loaded already, then you should just `// comment out` the jQuery library loading from the above code).

***And it's actually done.***

And just for fun I now tested the above with dummy content (from arrays with few of your logos) in your given PHP/HTML layout code (modified a bit), then I can confirm that it works. Here is the result, recorded in gif on my test page:

[image]

---

**Additional things:**

The only reason I do not paste here your layout code edited, fully working with the above carousel, because I would like to let you to do that, understanding and following the above steps. That is the only way you will learn to use additional javascripts and css and it’s important for you to improve your skills with that.

more info about using the above is here:
https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-an-infinite-client-logo-carousel-to-your-website.stml

The above carousel is working fine but if you need more exapmle, another code which you can check out and 'borrow':

https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE

and it's made already even with Bootstrap 4 :
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/client-or-partners-logo-slider (however I do not see any bootstrap in this (except the ‘container’) but it does not matter, this is just another version of the above, almost the same all of them).

There are a lot of versions of these ready to use carousels of this kind on the net. I hope the above can help you.

As you started to work on this and you now got stuck with the html divs, I copy here your edited K2 layout file and you can try this or use this in your layout. I of course did not tried this particular file since I do not have the required and called variables in it, but this is how your layout should look like. Check how the divs are restructured in the **- sponsors carousel section -** of the layout.

```
<?php

/**
 * @version     $Id: default.php 1766 2012-11-22 14:10:24Z lefteris.kavadas $
 * @package     K2
 * @author      JoomlaWorks http://www.joomlaworks.net
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006 - 2012 JoomlaWorks Ltd. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU/GPL license: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
 */
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
// $document->addScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'); // jQuery already loaded on the page
$document->addScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js');
?>

<?php if ($params->get('feed')): ?>
    <div class="k2FeedIcon">
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&format=feed&moduleID=' . $module->id); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_THIS_RSS_FEED'); ?>" target="_blank">
            <span><?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_THIS_RSS_FEED'); ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="k2ModuleBox<?php echo $module->id; ?>" >

<?php if ($params->get('itemPreText')): ?>
    <p class="modulePretext"><?php echo $params->get('itemPreText'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (count($items)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($items as $key => $item): ?>
    <article class="clearfix">
        <header>
           <?php if ($params->get('itemTitle')): ?>
                <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a></h2>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </header>
        <section class="content">
            <?php if ($params->get('itemImage') || $params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('itemImage') && isset($item->image)): ?>
                    <div class="img">
                        <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_CONTINUE_READING'); ?> &quot;<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>&quot;">
                            <img src="<?php echo $item->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $item->introtext; ?>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </section>

        <?php

        // here your sponsors carousel section starts -->

        ?>

            <?php if ($params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($item->extra_fields)): ?>

                <?php $sponsors = array(); ?>
                <?php foreach ($item->extra_fields as $key => $fieldname): // regroup fields per level?>
                    <?php if($fieldname->name === 'Url'):
                      $sponsors[$fieldname->alias][$fieldname->name] = $fieldname->url;
                    else:
                      $sponsors[$fieldname->alias][$fieldname->name] = $fieldname->value;
                    endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php
                    // define sort order for $sponsors array
                    $sort_order = array('Location','Collaborating Partner','Platinum', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze','Carbon Neutrality', 'Booth', 'Cocktail', 'Badge', 'Event Partner', 'Media', 'Global', 'USA', 'Europe', 'Asia');

                    // sort $sponsors based on sort order in $sort_order
                    usort($sponsors, function ($a, $b) use ($sort_order) {
                        return array_search($a['Level'], $sort_order) - array_search($b['Level'], $sort_order);
                    });                    
                ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <section class="customer-logos">

                            <h4 class="rotate col-md-2">Sponsors</h4>

                <?php foreach ($sponsors as $key=>$value) : ?>

                        <div class="slide">
                            <h4><small> <?php echo $value['Level'] ?> </small></h4>
                            <a href="<?php echo $value['Url'];?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $value['Logo'] ?></a>
                        </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>                

                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

    </article>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.customer-logos').slick({
                slidesToShow: 6,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 1000,
                arrows: false,
                dots: false,
                pauseOnHover: false,
                responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 4
                    }
                }, {
                    breakpoint: 520,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
</script>
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE** **ABOUT USING THE CAROUSEL CSS STYLE**

If you use javascript/jQuery all kinds of stupidity can happen on your site when you run these scripts (more if someone just starts with javascript), so here in this particular case happened that the slides stack up at the start of the carousel, however at the end of the carousel the slides were OK. It can cause a lot of headache to figure out why it happens, when everything looks correct.

Now in this case, if the **jQuery script** starts to run before the **css** is loaded then the first slides (or clones of slides) created by the script will be in different sizes (heights) than the later slides, due to the script trying to fill up white spaces in the slider. Thus the slides will stack up. The carousel will look a very ugly thing. And on the top of that you will feel really stupid. :) It happens when you copy the slider (carousel) css in one of your **custom.css** file which loads at the end of everything on your site.

So we have to load the **carousel.css** before the slider script (or carousel script, you name it). There are two easy way to do this.

**1.** Copy the whole **carousel css** on the top of your layout file between `<style></style>` tag. This is not the most optimal solution but it works very well. This is also the surest way to check if css cause problem.

**2** Create a **carousel.css** file, put it in your `yourjoomla/templates/yourtemplate/css` folder and load that file from the top of your layout file (in this case in K2 layout file), with the same method as you loaded the slick.js file at the beginning of your file.

```
$document->addStyleSheet('/templates/yourtemplate/css/carousel.css');
```

If the css file is not loaded then try:

```
$url = JPATH_ROOT . '/templates/yourtemplate/css/carousel.css'; // try it with or without opening slash (directory separator at the beginning of the path.

$document->addStyleSheet($url);
```

So, this should handle the stupidity actually if the slides are stacking up.

Just to make sure I updated the jQuery script with adding a $(window).load() function to the beginning of the script to hold back jquery to fire before page is fully loaded.

And finally in this individual case the source of the slider appearance problem was a css rule which had to be added to the css of the slider and set to:

```
.slick-track {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

This problem is not the same as feeding the slider with wrongly formulated, structured data, which was not a problem in this case at all.

Comment: Thanks @Zollie - A brilliant answer. I had a bit of an issue with the script so changed the document ready to jQuery and this stopped the errors. The problem I have now is that all of the logo's seem squashed to the left and do not scroll. http://tbli.sitewidehosting.co.uk/past-conferences/tbli-conference-nordic-2018 Have I missed something maybe?

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - You’re welcome! The only reasons I can imagine it is squashed in a corner on your page because you missed a <div> or </div> closing tag somwhere or the whole thing is pushed to the left by another <div class= “container...”>in your layout and this is outside of your main container div. and this one tries to push itself in the same row with the other div thus squashed, so you should check these Also make sure that this is wrapped in a <div class=“row”>, but I think you already did that, so that is not a problem.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 -  If the carousel animation is not working, it can be because the same jQuery library is loaded on your page 2 times or the bootstrap library is loaded 2 times. It could also be that one of them is not loaded on your page, however, the first scenario is more possible. Check your page header in the page source and make sure that the required libraries are there and not 2 times. You should play with this a bit and it will work.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - ohh, sorry, I just see that you linked your page, so I’ll check that myself soon, what could cause the problem there.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - Donna, I updated my answer with the edited layout and you can check that or use that in your layout. Theoretically it must work- Please give me a feedback on this after you tried.

Comment: Thank you once again, you truly are a star. This seems to be almost there now. 2 things I have spotted is that there it doesn't seem to start at the beginning of the logos (there should be 10 logos) If you manually drag the logos to the right (to see the right hand side) you can see there are many of the logos stacked on top of each other which in turn has increased the height of the div. Once again, thank you for your assistance in this. :)

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - Donna, at least it's moving. :) You're doing great! I'm checking it on your page what could cause that strange stack up at the beginning.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - Donna, at the moment what I see is that the problem is probably coming from the input data of the slides and as I think it derives from the $sort_order array and from usort function. The sort order array has 16 elements in it and as I see the slider is trying to move 16 indexed slides but it does not find images for that or something of the sort. At the same time, the static html is built correctly, but somehow the data source array what we are feeding this carousel now has more items in it. Please check what is in $sponsors array with var_dump($sponsors); // ...

Comment: and check how many items there in that and please write me some info about that. I suspect that this is the source of the problem of stacking a lot of items in the carousel. The array has to have the correct number of key and value pair. So there are more levels than urls and logo there, but it is not yet fully clear for me. I try to digest your code on this. :))

Comment: I’m not fully sure about the above, since the html looks good however. I’m checking that further of course...

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - Donna, please also try to feed the slider only with the logo images. So temporarly // comment out the urls and the levels from the foreach loop of the slider and see how it is moving without them, only with logo images.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - The above reasons in my comments are not the cause of the issue as I investigated now this much more deeply on your site. The only real reason I see for this strange stack up of slides at the beginning is that the carousel.css is loaded after the carousel jQuery script is running already. So the solution would be loading the carousel css before the jQuery. I'll write it down how to do that.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - Hi Donna, I just updated my answer at the end with details about the css placing and loading. Please repair that on your site and I hope that it will run OK then finally.

Comment: Thank you, I was pulled off on to another project but will jump back on to this later today and confirm back. Thanks for all your help to date.

Comment: The plot seems to thicken, I have created the carousel.css and checked that it is indeed loading before the slick.js in the <head> of the site but nothing seems to have changed. The slides still behave the same? It's all a bit odd to be honest. I really appreciate your time on this.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - let's try it the direct way. Please copy the css in the K2 layout file on the top somewhere between <style></style> tags and let's see what happens that way.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - the css must be loaded before the short script, (which we placed at the end of your K2 layout file) not before the slick.js library. That is important. We’ll solve it :)

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - probably the K2 module loads before the css files still and that’s why we have to place the css style on the top of the K2 layout file now.

Comment: I've added the style tags both at the very top of the file and after the $document->addScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js');?> But the results are still the same. It's all very odd. Hmm...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88613/discussion-between-zollie-and-dtorr1981).